# Why do geometry nodes need the first basic object to be created manually?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Could someone please help me to understand why we need the group input to create something in blender? why we cant directly create objects in the viewport via geometry nodes without first adding a mesh or something manually in the scene?

Comment: because the developers developed it like this? And maybe because modifiers needs objects/curves and that's what the GN modifier is?

Comment: Thanks @Chris I was confused. I mean how we can create infinite number of objects in blender through one simple cube in GN but then we cant create the first one? its a bit confusing.

Comment: The object used to set a gn node tree can be just a "pretext". No obligation to use it as output for the node tree. Instead you can create "any object" you want.

Comment: Thanks @lemon 

Comment: Origin and local axes are provided by the "pretext" object the GN modifier is added to. You need these in "Object Mode" to move/rotate/scale the geometry generated by the GN modifier. Every transformation inside GN is made relative to the carrying object.